# TreeView select TreeItem when pressing arrow keys instead of highlighting

Tags: treeview, vscode-extensions

I have a TreeView where the rows/TreeItems represent files (similar to the default VSCode search). When selecting a row the file is opened in a new view, but the focus remains on the TreeView.

Now, when moving the selection in the tree view using the up/down arrow keys I would like to open the other files (again, similar to the default search functionality in VSCode), but instead the rows are only highlighted and the only way to select them is to press space/enter. Is it possible to directly select the row if the user presses the up/down arrow keys?

[image: Example]